# How can I skip empty files with sed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I am using `sed` like this:

```
 sed -e 's/ *| */|/g'
   ${array_export_files[$loopcount]}>>$TEMPDIR/"export_file"_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$
```

under a while loop but problems come when the file is empty or contains nothing.

1. I don't want the `sed` to run if the file exists but is empty;
2. I don't want the `sed` to run if the file doesn't exist.

The complete code snippet is

```
while [ $loopcount -le $loopmax ]
do 
    if [ "$loopcount" -eq "$loopcount" ]
    then
        sed -e 's/ *| */|/g' ${array_export_files[$loopcount]}>>$TEMPDIR/"export_file"_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$
        tr "|" "\t" <"export_file"_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$>${array_export_files[$loopcount]}
        cp ${array_export_files[$loopcount]} "export_file"_${loopcount}_${testid}
        echo "Testing Starts Here"
        echo ${array_export_files[$loopcount]} "export_file"_${loopcount}_${testid}
        echo "Testing Ends Here"
    fi
  (( loopcount=`expr $loopcount+1`))
done
```

So I can't replace or use AND operator on the above if statement is there anyway to solve that?
if I use AND operator then it may skip the below whole code section will nor run I only wanted to skip the sed section conditionally.

Comment: You should make a new question with that new problem you introduce. Point 1 and 2 were answered. When you make the new question **explain** why you cannot replace or use AND operator, because that doesn't make sense. You can only replace what is already there (i.e. in use). What does `[ "$loopcount" -eq "$loopcount" ]` do? IMO that is always true.

Comment: @Anthon if I use AND operator then it may skip the below whole code  section will nor run I only wanted to skip the sed section conditionally.

Comment: @Anthon if you can use if inside the if statement mentioned it will be ok

Comment: Please look at that if statement and explain me what it does. It test if X equals X. That is always true, just replace it.

Comment: @Anthon I am totally agree with you and I have question why you use ; after if condition and double then symbol means what does ; signifies.

Comment: That ';' is necessary if you put the `if` and `then` on the same line.

Comment: Is the file you write to with `sed` supposed to be the same file you read again for `tr`?

Comment: @patrix yes sed supposed to be same file i read again for tr file name will be "export_file"_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$

Comment: The paths don't match (once it's with `$TEMPDIR`, once without), also you should use `>` instead of `>>` to store the result of `sed` (to avoid hard-to-debug bugs in case you get the same PID when running this again in a few weeks)

Comment: @patrix I am agree with you and Implemented the same.

Answer (score 4):

Bash has the `-s` option to test for existence **and** size greater than zero:

```
 -s file
          True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.
```

so you can do

```
if [ -s "${array_export_files[$loopcount]}" ]; then
   sed .......
fi
```

within the loop. Since the `if [ "$loopcount" -eq "$loopcount" ]` is always true you can just replace that:

```
while [ "$loopcount" -le "$loopmax" ]
do 
    if [ -s "${array_export_files[$loopcount]}" ]
    then
        sed -e 's/ *| */|/g' "${array_export_files[$loopcount]}" >>" $TEMPDIR/export_file_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$"
        tr "|" "\t" <"export_file_${testid}_${loopcount}_$$">"${array_export_files[$loopcount]}"
        cp "${array_export_files[$loopcount]}" "export_file_${loopcount}_${testid}"
        echo "Testing Starts Here"
        echo "${array_export_files[$loopcount]}" "export_file_${loopcount}_${testid}"
        echo "Testing Ends Here"
    fi
    (( loopcount = loopcount + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Hi Anthon please see edited question your answer is correct but how to use it.

Comment: additional `if` options (and how to use them) are listed [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Comment: @Aman, Just copy the line starting with `if` in the line before the one with the `sed` statement, and the line with `fi` after that line. If you update your question with the loop you are actually using, than I could have incorporated that wihtin the loop itself.

Comment: This will fail if file contains only blank lines.

Comment: @cuonglm Why? `echo -e '\n' > abcd ; if [ -s abcd ] ; then echo ok ; fi` gives `ok`.

Comment: @Anthon: Maybe I mis-understand the phrase `file is empty or contains nothing`.

Comment: @Anthon I have updated the code snippet

Comment: @cuonglm I overlooked that. Funny that one or the other would cause no second thoughts, but both makes you wonder what the OP exactly means.